# Swift adding button into view programatically with action

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add button to the programatically created view that I add to main view. I can't make action to work on a button. This is what I tried so far:

```
itemView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:240, height:375))
itemView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/0.0, green: 255.0/0.0, blue: 255.0/0.0, alpha: 0.05)
itemView.contentMode = .Center

buttonConnect = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:335, width:120, height:40))
buttonConnect.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0.6, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
buttonConnect.setTitle("Connect", forState: .Normal)
buttonConnect.tag = 3
buttonConnect.addTarget(itemView, action: "btnConnectTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchDown)
itemView.addSubview(buttonConnect)

self.addSubview(itemView)
```

Method on button click looks like this:

```
func btnConnectTouched(sender:UIButton!)
{
    print("button connect touched")
}
```

Can someone advice what is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand why you are adding a button inside a UIImageView. Even this is what you need, take a UIView and then put all other controls inside it. The reason your button is not clicking is that you have put it inside a UIImageView and for UIImageView , default value for userInteractionEnabled is false. so you need to enable it i.e.

```
 itemView.userInteractionEnabled = true;
```

Also set button target to 'self' rather than itemView.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks a lot! I changed `UIImageView` to `UIView` and also changed target to `self` and it works

Answer (score 2):

Try change the tarjet and the event

```
buttonConnect.addTarget(itemView, action: "btnConnectTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchDown)
```

into

```
buttonConnect.addTarget(self, action: "btnConnectTouched:", forControlEvents:. TouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong at the target:

```
// buttonConnect.addTarget(itemView, action: "btnConnectTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchDown)
    // using
    buttonConnect.addTarget(self, action: "btnConnectTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchDown)
    // or buttonConnect.addTarget(self, action: "btnConnectTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: @bla0009 did you change `itemView` to `self`?

Comment: @anthu yes, and still nothing happens on button click

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let buttonConnect = UIButton()      
    buttonConnect = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:335, width:120, height:40))
    buttonConnect.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0.6, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
    buttonConnect.setTitle("Connect", forState: .Normal)
    buttonConnect.tag = 3
    buttonConnect.addTarget(self, action: "btnConnectTouched:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)       
    self.view.addSubview(buttonConnect)
}

func btnConnectTouched(sender: UIButton!) {
     print("button connect touched");
}
```

Comment: change  forControlEvents:.TouchDown to forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside

Answer (score 0):

try  `buttonConnect.addTarget(itemView, action: "btnConnectTouched", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)`  without the `:` after `"btnConnectTouched"`

Answer (score 0):

If you can make following two changes in your code, it will work.

1. Replace UIImageView with UIView for itemView type and
2. Replace self.addSubview(itemView) with self.view.addSubview(itemView)

Your final code should look like....

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var itemView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:240, height:375))
    itemView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/0.0, green: 255.0/0.0, blue: 255.0/0.0, alpha: 0.05)
    itemView.contentMode = .Center

    var buttonConnect = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:335, width:120, height:40))
    buttonConnect.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0.6, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
    buttonConnect.setTitle("Connect", forState: .Normal)
    buttonConnect.tag = 3
    buttonConnect.addTarget(self, action: "btnConnectTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchDown)


    itemView.addSubview(buttonConnect)

    self.view.addSubview(itemView)

}

func btnConnectTouched(sender:UIButton!)
{
    print("button connect touched")
}
```

Try this one.... It's working for me....